# Webpack stuck on 94% asset optimization

Tags: optimization, vue.js, webpack, assets

While I'm changing in my Vue project "main.js" file or another ".js" files. My Webpack stuck on "94% asset optimization" forever. While I'm changing ".vue" files, then Webpack compiles successfully.

The only way to compile successfully Webpack after changing ".js" files, which I've found, it's to stop cmd by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, next again run `npm run dev` or `yarn run serve`.

Please, help. It's vital for me.